# Which way do excited electrons prefer to go, directly onto ground state or through intermediate energy levels?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, atomic-physics, atoms

Do excited electrons prefer to go directly onto the ground state or to go through an intermediate energy level?
(I know it depends on the probability weather electrons take a direct way to the ground state or go through intermediate energy levels but I want to know which has more probability)

Or, I can ask this like

When we excite an electron with a high energy photon(exciting it to a higher than second energy level), is it more likely to emit only one photon or to emit more than one photon?

Or,

If we have so many excited atoms(or many excited electrons in a single atom) and all are at a higher energy level(say at n=3), will more electrons emit 2 photons(by taking intermediate energy level) and fewer electrons emit 1 photon(by directly going into the ground state) **or** more electrons emit 1 photon and fewer electrons emit 2 photons?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Please look at the *simplified* sodium energy levels diagram in my answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/164168/79678). Those pathways heading downward have various transition probabilities. So think about what that implies.

Comment: Can anyone answer?

Comment: There are too many variables to give one simple answer. If you look at the neon lines linked figure  [here](https://stokes.byu.edu/teaching_resources/neonlines.html), just to pick the simple example of a common neon lamp, you see lots of emission lines. Be sure to read the text that accompanies the figure. There is no way to predict exactly how one neon excited atom might de-excite. For lots of excited neon atoms, as in the simple neon lamp, everything happens, with various transition probabilities.